# Parse .vmcx file of a VM created on Hyper-V host

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

Please help me with parsing a .vmcx file in C#.

I have created a Hyper-V role in Windows Server 2016 environment. I tried parsing .vmcx file as a text file using C# code snippet but I got output back in gibberish manner.

Comment: Did you see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/windows-virtualization-portal?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yes I did but couldnt find the relevant infrmation there

Comment: Did you try parsing with the methods?

Comment: I could not find a method to parse a file having extension .vmcx

Comment: The following link is for exporting.  At top of page there is link for visualizing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/exporting-virtual-machines